# DRY in controllers testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a lot code like this:

```
context 'with invalid attributes' do
  it "does not save link to database" do
    post :create, board_id: @board, link: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:link, url: "")
    expect(@board.links.count).to eq 0
  end

  it 're-render :new template' do
    post :create, board_id: @board, link: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:link, url: "")
    expect(response).to render_template :new
  end

  it 'sets an error flash message' do
    post :create, board_id: @board, link: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:link, url: "")
    expect(flash[:error]).to_not be_nil
  end
end
```

How can I DRY it? so I won't have `post :create, board_id: @board, link: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:link, url: "")` line in each case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try `before(:each)` block

```
context 'with invalid attributes' do
  before(:each) do
    post :create, board_id: @board, link: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:link, url: "")
  end

  it "does not save link to database" do
    expect(@board.links.count).to eq 0
  end

  it 're-render :new template' do
    expect(response).to render_template :new
  end

  it 'sets an error flash message' do
    expect(flash[:error]).to_not be_nil
  end
end
```

Comment: I was doing something wrong, cause I had it this way earlier and it didn't work, this time it works fine. It's a kind of magic :), thanks.